# Gettings json properties duktape

Tags: javascript, c++, json, duktape

everybody interested in a duktape framework. How could one integrate json properties with cpp code?

Assume we got following json:

```
{
    "name" : "duktape",
    "surname" : "duktapovich",
    "values" : [1,10]
}
```

If one would like to get corresponding value to "name" key, how could he achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved this by integrating one-header library JSON parser. Seems pretty cool.

https://github.com/nlohmann/json